# React: triggering state change in child component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a parent that is clearing the fields of several input fields (a reusable child component).

Parent:

```
const AdvancedSearch: FC<SearchProps> = memo(_props => {

// various other things

const resetFields = () => {
    setFields(data.initialFieldValues) // this replaces all text input with initial values of ''
    // trying to also clear the validation messages
}

return <React.Fragment>
    <TextField>
    <TextField>
    <TextField>
</React.Fragment>
}
```

Child:

```
const TextField: FC<TextFieldProps> = memo(props => {

  const [validationMessage, setValidationMessage] = useState(undefined as string | undefined) 

  let input = e.currentTarget.value

  const onTextChange = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    props.foo = input
    const error = validateNumericInput(input)
    setValidationMessage(error)
  }

  return <InputText value={props.foo}
  placeholder={props.placeholder}
  maxLength={props.maxLength}
  onChange={onTextChange}
  className={validationMessage ? `${classes.invalid}` : ''} />
}
```

The `resetFields` method in the parent successfully clears the input fields by replacing them with the initial values from `props.foo` but that obviously doesn't trigger the onChange event and I can't figure out how to reset the validationMessage via `resetFields`.

NB. the syntax could be wrong as I have truncated...

TIA

Gosh I can't remember what I've tried it feels like I've tried everything and getting very muddled haha.

I'm not sure whether I should be using `const [validationMessage, setValidationMessage] = useState(undefined as string | undefined)` in this child or something like this in the props:

```
export type TextFieldProps = {
    setValidationMessage?(validationMessage: string): string
}
```

Comment: I think this problem can be solved using React Refs,
https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html
By using this you will be able to use the objects of child from parent.

Comment: Ooooh I'm hopeful that it can... would you mind helping with how? I have put this in the parent ```const searchTextPropsRef = createRef<FilterSearchTextProps>()``` with ```searchTextPropsRef.current?.setValidationMessage('')``` in the `resetFields` method but it has not cleared the message.

Comment: And there's an `TS2722: Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'.` error

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a good use case for `useEffect`

```js
const TextField: FC<TextFieldProps> = (props) => {
  const [validationMessage, setValidationMessage] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!props.foo) setValidationMessage('');
  }, [props.foo]);

  ...
}
```

This hook executes the callback function whenever one of the dependencies in the array changes.

You can execute whatever code you want when `props.foo` changes.